# why icon not display in angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to use image viewer plugin in angular but my icon is not display 
here is my code

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  images=['https://images.pexels.com/photos/144240/goat-lamb-little-grass-144240.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb']
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u26jb5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

[image]

I am using this plugin
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-viewer
I already follow all steps .I don't know why it is not showing icons

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your url for image does not get sanitized by angular firewall. So angular is blocking the image from being loaded .
In order to sanititze the url

```
use safe pipe in code.
```

In view page:

```
<img [src]="catPictureUrl | safe: 'url'" alt="A Cat">
```

in app.component.ts:

```
public catPictureUrl: string = `https://www.petdrugsonline.co.uk/images/page-headers/cats-master-header`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know why is this happening but even font-awesome is installed but the template is not getting the styles. 
I tried adding the cdn to index.html and it just works fine.
Try adding cdn to index.html and you are good to go

`<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`